# How to create a high score in Unity from a Time.deltatime float?

Tags: unity, c#

When I play my game, it sets my score to 0 and does not change, no matter how high my float gets.

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class highscore : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text Highscore;   

    void Start () {    
        Highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Highscore", 0).ToString();    
    }
}
```

---

This is where the next page starts

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text ScoreText;


    public float playerScore = 0;


    void Update () {    
        playerScore += Time.deltaTime*10;

        {
            ScoreText.text = playerScore.ToString("0");
        }         
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo) {

        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Highscore", playerScore);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Friendly public service announcement: You should use `collisionInfo.collider.CompareTag("Obstacle")` instead of `collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle"` for better performance.

Comment: What score does not change? Is it `public float playerScore`, `public Text ScoreText` or `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Highscore", 0)`? Did you try to run the step by step debugger?

Comment: The Score that does not change is the    (Highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Highscore", 0).ToString();

Comment: I think its because my    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Highscore", playerScore); is not registering properly